# Integration of Trained Python ML Model with MERN App - Seeking Alternative Approaches

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, mern, web-development-server

Hello fellow developers!

I've been working on a MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) app and have successfully trained a Python ML model. Currently, I'm aware of one common approach to integrate these two components, which involves deploying the MERN app and building a connection with the model through an API.

However, I'm curious if there's an alternative method where I can simplify the process. Specifically, is it possible to deploy only the MERN app and utilize my trained ML model as a pickle file within the app?

I attempted to use the python-shell package from npm and achieved the desired predictions on my local system, where my virtual environment (venv) folder contained all the necessary Python packages. But, I'm unsure how to replicate this setup on a server, especially alongside the packages listed in my package.json for the MERN app.

Any insights or suggestions on how to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.